# Closing reader/input/socket within client

Tags: sockets, client-server, printwriter

I am currently writing a multi client chat program which works extremely well. The only issues I'm having now are if it is forcefully closed

I get this:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

I believe (from looking around) this is related to not closing the streams/socket properly within the client.. However, I have tried so many locations to close everything and I cant seem to figure it out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Heres the Client: (Without the GUI stuff)
Socket and streams are defined as attributes.

```
    public void connectToServer(){
      try{
         System.out.println("Waiting to connect");
         s = new Socket("localhost", 16789);   
         System.out.println("Connected");
         ClientThread ct = new ClientThread();
         ct.start(); 
         openStreams();         
      }

      catch(EOFException eofe){
         System.out.println("EOFException");
      }

      catch(IOException ioe){
         System.out.println("IO Error");
      }
   }

   public void openStreams(){

      try {
      //open input streams
         InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
         br = new BufferedReader(
                              new InputStreamReader(in));                             

      //open output streams

         OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
         pw = new PrintWriter(
                       new OutputStreamWriter(out));

      }
      catch(ConnectException ce){
         System.out.println("Could not connect");
      }
      catch(IOException ioe){
         System.out.println("IO Error");
      }
      catch(NullPointerException npe){
         System.out.print("Server offline");
         System.exit(0);
      }

   }

   public void closeStreams(){
      try{
         pw.close();
         br.close();
         s.close();
         }
      catch(IOException ioe){
         ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public void sendMsg(){    
      String message = enterMsg.getText();
      pw.println(message);
      pw.flush();
   }

   public void showMsg(){

      String show;
      try{
         while((show = br.readLine()) != null){
            chatArea.append(show + " \n");   
         }
      }
      catch(IOException ioe){
         chatArea.append("Error showing msg \n");
      }   
   }   

   class ClientThread extends Thread {
      public void run(){
            showMsg();
            closeStreams();
      }   
   }
}
```

And the specific section that the server is pointed to with the error:

```
     while( ( msg = br.readLine()) != null ){  
        System.out.print(msg);            
        // convert & send msg to client
           for(PrintWriter pw : clients){
              pw.println(userName + ":" + msg );
              pw.flush();
           }     

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

The most common causes of this are:

1. You wrote to a connection that had already been closed by the peer.
2. The peer closed the connection without reading all the pending incoming data.

The correct recovery is to close the socket and forget about that peer, but both are application protocol errors and should be investigated.

> this is related to not closing the streams/socket properly within the client

No it isn't. It is related to *prematurely* closing them in whichever of the peers didn't get this exception.

As for 'properly closing streams', just close the `PrintWriter.` Closing either the input or output stream of a `Socket` closes the other stream and the socket itself, and you should choose the outermost output stream/writer to close, so that it gets flushed.

Comment: Yep, I believe the issue is client side.. just cant figure out how to properly close the streams.